# Is it possible to add events to elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, edmx

I have an EDM model, I am trying to generate a dynamic UI for it, but it is not working to add events to more then 1 select.

In other words, it's only working for 1 select and not for more.

```
        function addEvents(id) {
          $('body').on('click', '#entities_' + id, function(event) {
            var $e = $(event.target);
            var entityIndex = $("#entities_" + id + " option:selected").index(); //$e.val();
            var entity = entities[entityIndex - 1];
            var columns = entity.property; // if index is not -1


            var $entities_cols = $("#entities_" + id + "_cols").empty();
            $.each(columns, function(index, e) {
              var selectColumnHtmlId = 'selectcolumn_' + e.name;
              var $selectColumnLabel = $('<label />', {
                'for': selectColumnHtmlId,
                text: e.name
              });
              $selectColumnLabel.appendTo($entities_cols);
              $('<input />', {
                type: 'checkbox',
                id: selectColumnHtmlId,
                value: e.name
              }).prependTo($selectColumnLabel);
            });

            if (id <= config.expandLimit)
              addExpand(++id, entity.navigationProperty);
          });
        }
```

Here is complete example - https://jsfiddle.net/ntbkyuau/3/

Answer (score 0):

Made it work by changing to this,

```
  function addEvents(id) {
          var $entities = $('#entities_' + id);
          $('body').on('click', $entities, function(event) {
            var $e = $(event.target);
            var entityIndex = $("#entities_" + id + " option:selected").index(); //$e.val();
            var entity = entities[entityIndex - 1];
            var columns = entity.property; // if index is not -1


            var $entities_cols = $("#entities_" + id + "_cols").empty();
            $.each(columns, function(index, e) {
              var selectColumnHtmlId = 'selectcolumn_' + e.name;
              var $selectColumnLabel = $('<label />', {
                'for': selectColumnHtmlId,
                text: e.name
              });
              $selectColumnLabel.appendTo($entities_cols);
              $('<input />', {
                type: 'checkbox',
                id: selectColumnHtmlId,
                value: e.name
              }).prependTo($selectColumnLabel);
            });

            if (id <= config.expandLimit)
              addExpand(++id, entity.navigationProperty);
          });
        }
```